# Counting the times each value from one list appears in a second list

Tags: python

I have a two lists. First is a list of animals seen of each of three trips. Second is a list of animal types.

```
In [1]:

animals_seen = ['cat dog mouse', 'cat dog', 'cat']
animal_types = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
```

I want the number of times an animal has been seen. In this case:

```
seen_count = [3, 2, 1]
```

That is, cat appears 3 times, dog 2 times, and mouse 1 time.

My strategy was to loop through each animal type, and for each one loop through each trip add 1 if that animal type was seen, then append that value to a new list called seen_count.

This is my code:

```
In [2]:

seen_count = []

for animal in animal_types:
    for seen in animals_seen:
        count = 0
        if animal in seen:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = count + 0
    seen_count.append(count)

print(seen_count)
```

However, the output doesn't make sense:

```
Out[4]:
[1, 0, 0]
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

This is a *perfect* use for a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

animals_seen = ['cat dog mouse', 'cat dog', 'cat']
animal_types = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']

seen_count = defaultdict(int)

for animal in animal_types:
    for seen in animals_seen:
        if animal in seen:
            seen_count[animal] += 1

print(seen_count)
```

Gives:

```
{'mouse': 1, 'dog': 2, 'cat': 3}
```

Comment: Without doing a `split`, won't you have problems with `catfish`?

Comment: @DSM, yeah, not really on topic, but I suppose rather than `if animal in seen` it would be better to do something like `any(animal == x for x in seen.split())`?

Comment: @Symmitchry: `animal in seen.split()` should have the same effect as `any(animal == x for x in seen.split())` and is much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `count = 0` is inside the inner loop, which makes it forget any previous values. The sole value of 1 in your output is thanks to the fact that there the last element contained the given animal. You need to initialize `count` with 0 inside the outer loop, but outside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
animals_seen = ['cat dog mouse', 'cat dog', 'cat']
animal_types = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']

print([sum(animal in ele.split()  for animal in animal_types) for ele in animals_seen])
[3, 2, 1]
```

If you want a dict:

```
counts = (sum(animal in ele.split()  for animal in animal_types) for ele in animals_seen)

print(dict(zip(animal_types, counts)))
{'mouse': 1, 'dog': 2, 'cat': 3}
```

Using your own code you need to put the count outside the inner loop and you can forget about the else:

```
seen_count = []

for animal in animal_types:
    count = 0 # will start at zero for each animal
    for seen in animals_seen:
        if animal in seen.split(): # use split or cat in catch will be True
            count += 1
    seen_count.append(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

More or less equivalent to the other answers is the following, which uses the `Counter` class from module `collections`

```
import collections

animals_seen = ['cat dog mouse', 'cat dog', 'cat']
c = collections.Counter()
for seen in animals_seen:
  c.update(seen.split())
  # c.update(set(seen.split()))
```

Output:

```
c
Counter({'cat': 3, 'dog': 2, 'mouse': 1})

list(c.values())
[3, 1, 2]

list(c.keys())
['cat', 'mouse', 'dog']
```

The main difference is that you can count any animal, even if it was not defined before.

**EDIT** in response to PadraicCunningham:
Use the commented-out line instead if an animal should only be counted once per trip.

Comment: fails on `'cat dog cat'` unless the OP wants repeated values

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: thanks for pointing that out. See my edit in response.

Answer (score 0):

```
animals_seen = ['cat dog mouse', 'cat dog', 'cat']
animal_types = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']

seen_count = [sum([each.count(animal) for each in animals_seen]) for animal in animal_types]

print seen_count

[3, 2, 1]
```

`String's` built-it **`count`** function works perfect.

```
>>> 'cat dog mouse'.count('cat')
1
>>> 'cat dog mouse cat'.count('cat')
2
>>> 'cat dog mouse catcat'.count('cat')
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is finding just the third element of `animals_seen` and the first element of `animal_types`. This is the number 1 of output.

It happens because of course `'cat'` is not equal to `'cat dog mouse'`.

I suggest you use the split function inside both for loops. Example of split function

```
seen="cat dog mouse" 
seen.split()
['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
```

This way you will be able to compare the result of this function with all animal_types.

Answer (score 0):

```
animals_seen = ['cat dog mouse', 'cat dog', 'cat']
animal_types = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']

seen = [0 for _ in animal_types]
for item in animals_seen:
    for index, animal in enumerate(animal_types):
        seen[index] += item.split(' ').count(animal)

print(seen)
```

Output

```
[3, 2, 1]
```